# Shell que lea multiples parametros en ciclo

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell-script

buenas tardes, tengo una duda:
como puedo leer multiples parametros desde una shell .sh
para luego ejecutar X comando.
estaba probando

```
#!/bin/bash
CONTADOR=0
while [ "$*" ]
do
let CONTADOR=$CONTADOR+1
echo "Argumento $CONTADOR: $1"
shift
done
```

pero esto me devuelve:

```
 Syntax error at line 3 : `while' is not matched.
```

la idea inicial es recibir parametros asi:

```
sh test.sh parametro1 parametro2 parametro3 parametro4
```

o idealmente:
    sh test.sh parametro1,parametro2,parametro3,parametro4

alguna idea de como poder solucionar esto?

Comment: ¿Qué quieres hacer exactamente con esos parámetros?

Comment: la idea es que el ciclo tome el valor del parametro para luego ejecutar X comando por ejemplo un rm $parametro, find -name $parametro, etc 
y que este se repita en equivalencia a los parametros ingresados

Comment: ¿pero quieres usar todos los parámetros? Es decir, si dices `sh test.sh bla ble bli` luego quieres que por ejemplo haga `rm bla ble bli`?

Comment: si, la idea es que ingresen X parametros, que seran nombres basicamente, y en base a eso tener el criterio para eliminar o buscarlos, por eso al ser un ciclo quedaria asi:
rm bla
rm ble
rm bli
...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es, para el primer caso que es leer los parámetros ingresados al momento de ejecutar el script, puede ser leer del array de parámetros `$@` y operar según su tamaño `$#`. Para el segundo caso, con los parámetros separados por comas, necesitas la función *builtin* de bash `read` e indicarle que la entrada (los parámetros de ejecución) la lea utilizando la coma como delimitador.

Para el primer caso, una opción sería la comentada.

```
#!/bin/bash
main1() {
    echo "___________"
    echo ""
    echo "   $FUNCNAME  "
    echo ""
    echo "___________"

    declare CONTADOR=0

    while [[ "$#" > 0 ]]  #  Mientras la cantidad de parametros
                          #+ en el array de $@ sea mayor a 0
    do
        let CONTADOR=$CONTADOR+1
        echo "El parametro $CONTADOR es: $1"
        shift  # Esto recorre el array de parametros $@
    done
}

main1 $@
```

Y su salida sería de la forma.

```
$ ./parametros.sh p1 p2 p3
___________

   main1

___________
El parametro 1 es: p1
El parametro 2 es: p2
El parametro 3 es: p3
```

Para la parte de los valores separados con coma sería de esta manera.

```
#!/bin/bash
main2() {

    echo "___________"
    echo ""
    echo "   $FUNCNAME  "
    echo ""
    echo "___________"

    declare CONTADOR=0

    while read -rd , parametro || [ -n "$parametro" ]  #  Lee utilizando las comas como delimitador
                                                       #+ y asigna la entrada a la variable "parametro"
                                                       #+ y para evitar escaparse la ultima "palabra"
                                                       #+ nos aseguramos que no sea vacia la ultima
                                                       #+ cadena capturada
    do
        let CONTADOR=$CONTADOR+1
        echo "El parametro $CONTADOR es: $parametro"
    done <<< "$@"  # Le pasamos los parametros separados por coma.
}

main2 $@
```

Y su salida sería la siguiente.

```
$ ./parametros.sh p1,p2,p3
___________

   main2

___________
El parametro 1 es: p1
El parametro 2 es: p2
El parametro 3 es: p3
```

La clave está en las variables `$@`, `$#` y las funciones `shift` y `read`.

La variable `$@` expande los parámetros posicionales, la variable `$#` expande la **cantidad** de los parámetros posicionales.

`shift` recorre los parámetros posicionales, es decir, el parámetro "n+1" ahora lo vuelve el "n". `read` lee del *stdin* o de un descriptor de archivo y la primera palabra (delimitada por el IFS) se asigna al primer nombre después de la invocación de `read`.

Comment: nota aclaratoria: el `shift` "descarta" el primer parámetro y mueve todo el array hacia la izq, haciendo variar a `$#` (cantidad) y `$1` primer parámetro

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda y explicacion!